# Windows Home Server equivalent

Tags: windows, server, mediaserver

What Windows Home Server equivalents are available for Ubuntu? I am specifically looking for file sharing, backups, media streaming etc...

Obviously Ubuntu can do all of these out of the box, but I was wondering whether there was a nice interface out there that would cover it all...

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the wonderful [Amahi](http://www.amahi.org/) - the latest release is based on Ubuntu 12.04, rather than Fedora as before, and offers plenty! If you've got a spare pc give it a try. It can do all the stuff you'd want from a mediaserver.

Comment: @e100 even if the new release is based in Ubuntu further problems will not be answerable here. It would be off-topic.

Comment: fair enough, but the answer was out of date.